# Project Euler #22 in Java(off by 7 364 934)

Tags: java, regex, string

Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938  53 = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

I am getting 863833348 but the correct answer is 871198282. I am not sure what is wrong, I have tried all things but could not figure out the problem.

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Pattern testRegEx=Pattern.compile("[^\\\"]\\w+[^\\\",]");

    String line;
    String filePath="//Users//painkillerfff//Documents//names.txt";
    BufferedReader readTextFile=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

    List<String> nameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    while((line=readTextFile.readLine())!=null){
        //System.out.println(line);
        Matcher matcher=testRegEx.matcher(line);
        while(matcher.find()){
            nameList.add(matcher.group());
            //System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(nameList);

    long sumOfWords=0;
    long namePoint=0;
    long nameRank=1;
    for(String name: nameList){
        namePoint=0;
        for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
            namePoint+=alphabet.indexOf(name.charAt(i))+1;
        }
        namePoint=namePoint*nameRank;
        sumOfWords+=namePoint;
        nameRank++;
    }
    System.out.println("The Total Points is: "+sumOfWords);
}
```

Comment: Make sure the first and last names are being processed.  What is that regexp doing?

Comment: The file consists of only names, there is no last name or first name categorization. Here is the link to the file http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: I mean, verify the first name in the file, and the last name in the file, are being processed.  That is, that you're not dropping one of them into the bit bucket.

Comment: I just wanted to highlight the fact that this is not a homework problem, I am just doing this out of interest. If that is the reason behind the down vote. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: I have already verified that, it is in fact processing both the last name in the input file and first name in the input file.

Comment: I count 5162 commas = 5163 names.  Is that what you expected?

Comment: Is there a duplicate name, and Collections.sort() is removing it?

Comment: I checked the size of the ArrayList before the sort and after the sort. It is 5130 before the sort and after the sort so there is no change duplicate removal.

Comment: My guess is that your regexp is flawed.  Unless I'm totally insane, you're missing 33 names.

Comment: I can see that there are 5162 just by doing a simple count. What can be the flaw in the regex it looks alright. I am still thinking what might be wrong with the regex

Comment: I confirmed the regexp isn't agreeing with a split String.split().  The truth is, I don't understand your regexp.  What is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp is flawed somehow.  A count of commas shows there are 5163 names, yet you post there are 5130.

Help me understand the regexp and we'll probably figure it out.

This is my version - no regexp needed.

```
    while ((line = readTextFile.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    line = sb.toString();
    line = line.replace("\"", "");
    String[] a = line.split(",");
    System.out.println(a.length);
```

Of course you should use real variable names, not `a` ;-)

EDIT - I changed your regexp to

```
    Pattern testRegEx = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
```

and it returned 5163 names.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out while I was testing the regex with unix. Thanks for your help though. I worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class P22 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String content = null;
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("p022_names.txt")));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.getStackTrace();
        }
        String words[] = content.split("\",\"");
        int total = words.length;
        words[0] = words[0].substring(1);
        words[total-1] = words[total-1].substring(0,words[total-1].length()-1);
        Arrays.sort(words);
        int sumOfProducts = 0;
        int base = 'A'-1;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < total ; i++ ) {
            int sum = 0;
            int len = words[i].length();
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < len ; j++ ) {
                sum+=words[i].charAt(j)-base;
            }
            sumOfProducts+=sum*(i+1);
        }
        System.out.println(sumOfProducts);
    }
}
```

**Total time: 56 ms**

**Explanation:**

- The file is read and it is stored into a string
- The string is splitted by `","`. The result is an array of words that has to be adjusted for the first and the last words because there is an extra `"` at the beginning / end.
- The array is sorted using `Arrays.sort`
- For every word, the position is `i+1` (because `i` starts from `0`) and the sum is calculated using the fact that a `char` is actually an integer.